# Aerospike Collectd plugin with Python3 on Ubuntu 20 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, aerospike, collectd, aerospike-ce

I have tried to run the Aerospike Collectd plugin ([https://github.com/aerospike-community/aerospike-collectd][1]), however, I have run into several problems/issues.

When trying to build with pip or pip3, it fails both times. With pip3, I have been able to install requirements by changing the aerospike client version to 4.0 from the old value 3.10.

Additionally, I had to change aerospike_plugin.py code to correctly import *ServerName* value from the new library of aerospike client 4.0.

I am having this python issue:

```
Nov  5 23:34:39 aerospike5 collectd[182769]: Unhandled python exception in read callback: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lookup'
Nov  5 23:34:39 aerospike5 collectd[182769]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov  5 23:34:39 aerospike5 collectd[182769]:   File "/usr/lib/collectd/aerospike_plugin.py", line 867, in read#012    reader(self.client, config, meta, self.emit)
Nov  5 23:34:39 aerospike5 collectd[182769]:   File "/usr/lib/collectd/aerospike_plugin.py", line 367, in cluster#012    emit(meta, 'services', len(services), ['cluster'])
Nov  5 23:34:39 aerospike5 collectd[182769]:   File "/usr/lib/collectd/aerospike_plugin.py", line 814, in emit#012    for type, value in self.schema.lookup(category, metric, value):
Nov  5 23:34:39 aerospike5 collectd[182769]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lookup'
Nov  5 23:34:39 aerospike5 collectd[182769]: read-function of plugin `python.aerospike_plugin' failed. Will suspend it for 640.000 seconds.
```

Could you please help me fix the error or if anyone had experience with this piece of software?
Thank you all in advance.
[1]: https://github.com/aerospike-community/aerospike-collectd

Comment: Hope the git issue itself you seem to have posted will have some traction (https://github.com/aerospike-community/aerospike-collectd/issues/18).

Comment: @Meher I hope for that one too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really a programming question. It's a duplicate of an issue raised in a GitHub repo.